# Using Behat and Mink how to select the second or third item from a drop down using CSS selectors?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, behat, mink

Using behat mink with selenium2, how do i select 2nd or the 3rd item from a drop down using css. For some reason using nth child didn't work.

It works fine when i select using the item name. But the items in the drop down are not constant, they keep changing very often. That is the reason i want select by the item number.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO! As you are new to SO, you might want to read the following help pages: ["How do I ask a good question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Selecting the "3rd" item in a drop-down isn't very common, but try something like this:

```
$select = $this->getSession()->getPage()->find('css', '#my-select-element');
$options = $select->findAll('css', 'option');
$secondOption = $options[1];

$this->getSession()->getDriver()->selectOption(
    $select->getXpath(),
    $secondOption->getValue()
);
```

See if that works - I haven't actually tried this yet!

Comment: Thank you for your Answer

I tried using this

$session = $this->getSession(); 
$elements = $session->getPage()->find('css', '#search_student_type_chosen');
$options = $elements->findAll('css', 'option');
$secondOption = $options[1];
$secondOption->click();

I get this message when i run this test

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in Tests/bootstrap/FeatureContext.php line 593